# Can lan connected PC get infected if it's uninfected router is connected to main infected ruter?

Tags: networking, router, security

Can second PC get infected if main PC/Router gets infected, considering that the second PC is lan connected to second uninfected router that is lan connected to main infected router?

Comment: As long as they are on the same LAN such that you can access (for e.g. ping or port scan) another uninfected device, it can be thought of as *compromised* as the virus may use exploits against devices on the same LAN (which, in a home network, many are configured to have relatively lenient firewall rules, which doesnt help...) so, yes, it s *possible* to get infected, but depends on the virus at hand. If you need to be absolutely careful, wipe any infected devices/run an AV scan, upgrade the router's firmware, and only install programs/firmware from trusted sources.

Answer (score 1):

Once any node in your local network is infected, the whole network is compromised.

As all external communications pass through the main router, you are open to attack.
These attacks are called
[Man-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)
and can bypass HTTPS protections, steal passwords and much more.

If you suspect your router of being infected, factory reset it.
Check also for newer firmware which might be less vulnerable to such attacks.
Verify the router's firewall and beware of port-forwarding or DMZ.